# apache cant reach html subdirectories and getting 404 error

Tags: html, css, linux, apache, centos

i have a problem with my apache server.
i dont know why, but iv'e copied files from one apache server to another, same owners to the folders and same '777' chmod.
but in the other server, my application is trying to use css files from /var/www/html/css folder, and Although this folder contain my files, im getting 404 error when my web app is trying to reach the files.

Comment: Not related, but: [Why shouldn't /var/www have chmod 777](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777).

Comment: i gave it by default

Comment: This should only be used as a last resort when testing and you should never have to leave permissions set at 777, at least remove the execution permission. Also, do you have the same config as you did with the other apache server?

Comment: i'm the only one that use this server so i don't scare to leave the permissions at 777. by saying "same config". do you mean the httpd.conf file?

Comment: it's still a bad practice, no matter what. It's like leaving the keys inside your car. If you learn to do it, but your car is mostly parked inside a garage, nothing bad will happen. But once you do it in a public place, the risk of your car being stolen is much higher. Not just the `httpd.conf`, all files that are included have to be there too.

Comment: Ok, I did what you said. And still I'm having the same problem. I tried to access http://my-URL/Html

Comment: Sorry the comment broke. So I entered this address and I got "you don't have permission to access /html/ on this server

Comment: This sounds like HTTP code 401/403. This doesn't have to do anything with file system permissions, it has something to do with how you've configured access permissions to the server from outside. It's difficult to help in any way without seeing what your config looks like and what you've tried so far. Try googling the error you get, I'm sure that it was answered here on SO already.

Answer (score 0):

What user running apache?
Which permissions (owner) for files?

[This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7) article can help you with apache settings.